# Postgres: ArgumentException for bit_string(1) column in datatable

Tags: c#, postgresql, datatable

I am trying to fill datatable from simple select:

```
 string queryTableData = string.Format("select * from {0}", fullTableName);

 var command = new NpgsqlCommand(queryTableData, connection);
 DataTable table = new DataTable();
 table.Load(command.ExecuteReader());
```

But if table has `bit` column:

```
column_name: column1
data_type: bit
character_maximum_length: 1
udt_name: bit
```

I get `ArgumentException`:

```
Type of value has a mismatch with column typeCouldn't store <True> in column1 Column.  Expected type is BitString.
```

Any ideas how to fix it? I failed at googling solution for this.

Answer (score 1):

On the PostgreSQL side, `true` is one data type, and `bit` is another. They're not  compatible.

The value `true` is Boolean; you can't cast a Boolean as bit.

```
select cast(true as bit)
```

```
ERROR:  cannot cast type boolean to bit
```

You also can't cast a `bit` as Boolean.

```
select cast(b'1' as boolean);
```

```
ERROR:  cannot cast type bit to boolean
```

If you must use bit columns as if they were Boolean, use b'0' and b'1'. But you'll have to use the same values in comparisons. Expressions like `where column1` or `where column1 = true` won't work. You have to use expressions like `where column1 = b'1'`.

You *can* cast integers and strings as Boolean. These all return the Boolean value `true`.

```
select cast(1 as boolean);
select cast(42 as boolean);
select cast('1' as boolean);  -- But cast('42' as boolean) throws a syntax error
select cast('y' as boolean);
select cast('t' as boolean);
select cast('true' as boolean);
select cast('yes' as boolean);
```

---

If I understand your error correctly, you have type Boolean on the database side, and type bit(n) on the DataTable side. If you can't somehow make those types compatible (that is, different), you can convert the type in SQL using a CASE expression. I'm not sure whether this will work with your code, though.

```
select case when column1 = true then b'1'
            when column1 = false then b'0'
            -- Think about what to do with NULL.
       end as boolean_to_bit
from your_table_name;
```

```
boolean_to_bit
"bit"
--
1
0
(null)
```

Comment: I dont want to compare and I dont have intend to cast anything. All I need - is to read data to empty datatable. Is there a way except joining with information_schema.columns and casting in the type that will not fail?

Comment: I believe that problem is in DataTable itself, surprisingly it can not read data and cast it internally.